# How to trim multiple lines in a string Android?

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin, text

Hi we need a formatted string for our application.

Expected output :

```
Blow the candles real hard,
Coz now you have aged,
Don't pretend so much my dear,
Don't behave so sage,
Happy birthday to you,
Have a nice day,
Make the most of your day!
```

I want to format a string as shown above, when I use trim() function for string it gives the result as

```
Blow the candles real hard,
 Coz now you have aged,
Don't pretend so much my dear,
 Don't behave so sage,
 Happy birthday to you,
 Have a nice day,
Make the most of your day!
```

I want to remove the white spaces at the start of each line. I have used these functions below, it trimmed the start and end of the string but not lines.

```
   poemText = poemText.trimMargin()
   poemText = poemText.trimIndent()
   poemText = poemText.replace("\n ", "\n")
   for(line in poemText.lines())
   {line.trim()}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: My bad: My first answer not cover the case where there are spaces in the beginning of the text, nor in the end of each line, I changed it you can use the new solution instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use replace with regex like this:

```
poemText = poemText.replace("""^\s*|\s*$""".toRegex(), "")
                   .replace("""\s*(\r|\n|\r\n)\s*""".toRegex(), "\n")
```

[**Code example**](https://pl.kotl.in/JMhIT8J_W)

The first replace will remove all the spaces in the beginning and in the end of of text, and the second one will remove the spaces in the end and in the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^\h+` to match 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars from the start of the string and use `(?m)` to enable multiline.

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
     val poemText = """
Blow the candles real hard,
 Coz now you have aged,
Don't pretend so much my dear,
 Don't behave so sage,
 Happy birthday to you,
 Have a nice day,
Make the most of your day!"""
    
    println(
        """(?m)^\h+"""
        .toRegex()
        .replace(poemText, "")
    )
```

Output

```
Blow the candles real hard,
Coz now you have aged,
Don't pretend so much my dear,
Don't behave so sage,
Happy birthday to you,
Have a nice day,
Make the most of your day!
```

See a [Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/1HC2Ur)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
poemText = poemText.trim().replaceAll("\n ", "\n")
```

Because you have white spaces between sentences so first trim() to get rid of the start and the end of the String and then replace the comma and the white spaces in between with`\n`

Comment: This will change all-white spaces with new lines. it won't help

Comment: my bad, edited the answer. Of course if you have `,` between all the lines

Comment: not helped :(, not all poems ends with ", "

Comment: I was expecting that. so here is an idea. if the app is not published yet, you can make sure that the text is always formatted with a `, ` (comma + white space) between the lines (if you are receiving the string from the user or from your premade database, makes no difference).

Comment: just ran my solution in the IDE and it works, as well.

Comment: thank you for the efforts, but didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you can turn java into kotlin

```
 String text = "Blow the candles real hard,\n " +
            "    Coz now you have aged,\n " +
            "    Don't pretend so much my dear,\n " +
            "    Don't behave so sage,\n " +
            "    Happy birthday to you,\n " +
            "    Have a nice day,\n " +
            "    Make the most of your day!";

    String[] lines = null;
    lines = text.split("\n");

    String newText = "";
    for(int i = 0 ; i<lines.length ; i++){
        newText = (newText + lines[i]).trim()+"\n";
    }

    Log.e("newText",newText);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it looks like an excessive operation for this task :)